# Web crawling and robots.txt

Tags: php, wget

I used wget to 'download' a site.

wget -r http://www.xyz.com

i) It returns a **.css** file, a **.js** file, and **index.php** and an image **img1.jpg**

ii) However, there exist more images under **xyz.com**. I typed **www.xyz.com/Img2.jpg** and hence

got an image.

iii) But **index.php** refers to a single image, i.e. **img1.jpg**.

iv) A robot file accompanies it that contains **Disallow:**

What change should be made in the command line to return everything under **xyz.com**, that are not

referenced in **index.php**, but are static in the directory.

Comment: There is no way to know what resources exist on a server short of guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. How should `wget` know about other files in the directory unless you have a link to the file somewhere?

Comment: True... My perception is that, by default the landing page is "index.php" or "index.html". So wget scans "index.php" to return only the image(files) that it refers... Is there any way to pull down all images under "xyz.com" that aren't referenced anywhere...?

Comment: Only if the webserver is configured to supply a list of the files in that directory (usually by not containing a index.html file)

Comment: Only if list directory is enabled and maybe some other low security stuff too.

Comment: Does that mean that even if you get few files, they are the ones that are referenced in "index.php"...?

Comment: Exactly. `wget -r` works by downloading the file the server returns as an answer to your request and, if it's a HTML file, parsing it and downloading all files mentioned in this first one. If any of the downloaded references are HTML files too, they will in turn be parsed again, until all files from the server that are reachable from the given URL are downloaded.