# Web crawling and robots.txt - II

Tags: php, html, image, wget

Similar scenario as one of my previous question:

1. Using `wget`, i type the following to pull down **images** from a site (sub-folder):

   ```
    wget -r -A.jpg http://www.abc.com/images/
   ```
2. I get two images from the above command - Img1, Img2.
3. The index.php file in `http://www.abc.com/images/` refers to only `Img2.jpg` (saw the source).
4. If i key in `http://www.abc.com/images/Img4.jpg` or `http://www.abc.com/images/Img5.jpg`, i get two separate images.
5. But these images are not downloaded by wget.
6. How should I go about retrieving the entire set of images under `http://www.abc.com/images/`?

Comment: if html document at `http://www.abc.com/images/` refers to `img2.jpg`, that is all you can get. If that page refers to other `text/html` pages that refer to other images you can get them too. If you're trying to download images not referenced by any html document... sorry, you can't.

Comment: @Salman: true.. but i should get only Img2.jpg as per 3)... index.php refers to a .css, .js and Img2.jpg...

Comment: there is probably a good reason why that happened. You can try adding `--verbose --output-file=diagnostics.txt` to the wget command to see why it downloads *img1.jpg*. Having said that, you can still download all images inside `http://www.abc.com/images/` directory by scanning entire `http://www.abc.com/` and use accept/reject/include/exclude parameters to filter jpg images inside `/images/`.

Comment: This appears to be the *same* question as before — you seem to be asking how to get `wget` to download images which you can only find by guessing at the URLs. What does it have to do with robots.txt though?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web crawling and robots.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520321/web-crawling-and-robots-txt)

Comment: @Quentin: May be due to the contents of robot.txt, u cud know the access rights? I have mentioned in my Q that is is the same scenario...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want but try this:

```
wget --recursive --accept=gif,jpg,png http://www.abc.com
```

This will:

1. Create a directory called `www.abc.com\`
2. Crawl all pages on `www.abc.com`
3. Save all .GIF, .JPG or .PNG files inside the corresponding directories under `www.abc.com\`

You can then delete all directories except the one you're interested in, namely, `www.abc.com\images\`

Crawling all pages is a time consuming operation but probably the only way to make sure you that you get all images that are referenced by any of the pages on *www.abc.com*. There is no other way to detect what images are present inside *http://abc.com/images/* unless the server allows directory browsing.