# Crawling/scraping .jpg images off of a webpage - 403 Forbidden error

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, wget

Is there a possibility of crawling/scraping .jpg images off of a webpage using Python?

example:
Site (http://thisisthesiteimcrawling.com/images)
I want to grab all .jpg images from this directory. I know there are many.  When I try to use wget, I get the 403 Forbidden error.

With the full path of the image:
Example: (http://thisisthesiteimcrawling.com/images/image1.jpg) you'll be able to see/retrieve the image via browser/wget...

With Python, is there a way to crawl a webpage for *.jpg even if the dev has disabled directory listing on the original /images/ directory?

Also, changing user agent in wget and similar does not work, the robots.txt is not allowing this directory either. The site is using plain http.

Comment: Can you not provide the actual URL?

Comment: [Directory](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/aboutparliament/img/photo/child.abduction/) vs. [Full URL](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/aboutparliament/img/photo/child.abduction/11-09-27-mediation-04.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

See answer [Web crawling and robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520321/web-crawling-and-robots-txt?rq=1)
most likely it's not possible to list the directory content, hence not possible to crawl it without having direct links...